# Getting the are the ISS is flying over using reverse geocoder

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-conversion, reverse-geocoding

I use the following code in order to get the city the iss is flying over. I used the code from the astro-pi tutorial(https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/code-for-your-astro-pi-mission-space-lab-experiment/2):

```
import reverse_geocoder
from orbit import ISS

coordinates = ISS.coordinates()
coordinate_pair = (
    coordinates.latitude.degrees,
    coordinates.longitude.degrees)
location = reverse_geocoder.search(coordinate_pair)
print(location)
```

This is what i get

```
[OrderedDict([
    ('lat', '42.82701'),
    ('lon', '-75.54462'),
    ('name', 'Hamilton'),
    ('admin1', 'New York'),
    ('admin2', 'Madison County'),
    ('cc', 'US')
])]
```

What kind of data is this ? and how can i for example print out only `name` and get `Hamilton`

Comment: `print(location[0]['name'])` ? Have a look at: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Maurice Meyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7216865/maurice-meyer) helped me solve the issue

```
print(location[0]['name'])
```

Comment: This answer might be improved with an explanation of why a `list` of `OrderedDict` be accessed like a `list` of `dict`.